# Dist-Upgrade to a different Distro-Flavour

Tags: snap, migration

I made the mistake to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Now I'm desperately looking for an defined migration path ongoing from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to a system (perhaps 20.04 LTS based) that does not require Snapd to be enabled in the system configuration (for normal operations).

Which migration options exist?

> Just as an illustration example as it caused some comments and it is necessary to draw the line that the question does not appear off-topic: If any of the Ask-Ubuntu-on-topic distros (? Flavors? Spin-offs? Any Ask-Ubuntu offical wording here in case of mismatch!) (next to 18.04 LTS / 20.04.2 LTS) would not ship with Snapd by default, this *would* also be a hypothetically considerable acceptable example. Another one would be to answer that there is no migration path by any of the Spin-Offs and this is known (or an unknown known).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121145/discussion-on-question-by-hakre-dist-upgrade-to-a-different-distro-flavour).

Answer (score 7):

None whatsoever. The normal method is to make a backup of your personal files and reinstall a version you want to use and there is no release without snap.

You can however remove snap from your current installation with

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

That will remove anything snap related and you can install each of the non-snap versions to replace them.

Comment: However, keep in mind a lot of things may be removed that you want without Debian package equivalents - a lot of things are just Snapped now by default in the Ubuntu 20.04+ environment and metapackages install the snaps.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about this suggestion and how serious it is. Is it possible to properly run an Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS without Snapd? I'm currently testing by disabling it, but already on the dist upgrade there was some kind of force to use Snapd (suddenly). The dist upgrade somehow didn't care it was already explicitly not activated on 18.04 LTS on my system, but still making is a non-optional suggestion.

Comment: Running without snapd has been OK for me, although the Ubuntu software store looses functionality, and there may be applications that are not available otherwise.  I have not found any yet...

Comment: @CharlesGreen don't forget you are vastly more experienced than the OP at solving issues which the OP may struggle with, if I may be so bold to say.

Comment: @24601 Perhaps - I do not view my skills as being so advanced however, and bask in the glow of the awesome computing knowledge of other presented on this site.  I'm a huge fan of backups, and a full install of Ubuntu and all programs I want takes less than an hour.  Learn by doing....

Comment: I agree with Charles.  Create a good backup, know how to restore it and start tweaking your system. My experience in Ubuntu taught me how to reinstall my system within 20 minutes with almost zero downtime (I keep using firefox during the installation and the downtime is 1 reboot).

Comment: @Rinzwind: Would you consider the backup that ships with Ubuntu (18.04) a "good backup" in this context?

Comment: Never used it. Files on my machine that are older than a day and are not downloaded files are automatically rsync'd to a NAS every time I turn my machine on. The ability to restore is more important ;-) deja-dup seems to be pretty good (not a lot of issues on AskUbuntu)

Comment: It could be read that's about `$HOME` and the downloads therein, yes fine. I also keep out docker images. And would add the list of apt installed software so it's easy re-install for that purpose.